# How can I filter a Django queryset for the most appearing element?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter one of my Django models for the most appearing element (in this case, the user with the most sales) and then sort it afterwards. After a bit of digging, I came to the following solution:

```
best_seller = [seller for seller in Sale.objects.values_list("seller", flat=True).annotate(s_count=Count("seller")).order_by("-s_count")]
```

`seller` is a column inside of my `Sale` table containing a User object. The given code only returns an array containing (probably?) the ID/IDs of the found users instead of the queryset itself.

Comment: The queryset itself is the ID of the users because that is what is stored inside of the Sale objects. If you take those IDs you should be able to find the users.

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: Wait, you do `best_seller = [seller for seller in queryset]`, which is a) equivalent to `list(queryset)` - no listcomp needed - and b) effectively converts a "queryset itself" to a list, If you need a queryset, try not converting?.. If you need a queryset of full Seller objects, please update your question to make this understandable.

Comment: @SUTerliakov: I think he wants the sellers, not the sales.

Comment: Ah, that also makes sense. Please update the question to remove ambiguous interpretations.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the queryset:

```
Seller.objects.annotate(s_count=Count('sale_set')).order_by('-s_count')
```

This will return the `Seller`s order by the number of *related* `Sale`s.